#  Why is QTWebKit so much behind Google Chrome (Chromium)

Tags: qt, google-chrome, standards, qtwebkit, chromium

I have used the newest release of QtWebKit, that is version 2.2. But I must say it is nowhere near the current release of chromium. It lacks many CSS properties, it lacks anti aliasing, it renders rotated pictures ugly, the selection of text is implemented in chromium a lot nicely, it scales everthing a lot nicer on page zoom, only to name a few.

1. How much does google contribute back to webkit source?
2. Is it possible to use chromium version of webkit with Qt?
3. How can I solve this problem and assure that my web application will render wonderfully like it used to render in Chromium?
4. How come to such differences in source codes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) They contribute a bit back. I have no idea how much exactly other than a reasonable amount.

2) It's definitely doable, it's probably just a C++ engine you'd need to wrap in Qt.

3) Keep in mind that whilst Chromium is running a modified version of WebKit they've also got a load of other tools running on top of it to get the experience just so.

4) Such differences as they have such different needs. WebKit needs to be usable pretty much in multiple aspects, Chromium just needs to be as good as possible.